# Spring boot SecurityContextHolder: principal is changing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have encountered an issue with the SecurityContextHolder.

Given an Thymeleaf Template where userdetails can be changed and submitted. As admin I am entering the /edit Controller. So far everything is fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{username}/edit", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable String username, ModelMap model) {
    User user = userService.findUser(username);
    User loggedInUser = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    ....

}
```

In the loggedInUser variable I see the admin user. That works as expected:
[image]

When the form is submitted. I check the pricipal object again. Now it suddenly changed to the user I am currently editing.

Form snippet

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" th:action="@{/users/save}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
   <input type="hidden" id="old_username" name="old_username" th:value="${user.username}" required>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" th:field="${user.username}" required>

....
</form
```

Receiving POST Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/save", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(User user, HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redir) {

User loggedInUser = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

....
```

Here the loggedInUser changed to the user being edited:
[image]

What is going on?

Comment: You may be setting `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication`

Comment: negative, thats not being called

Comment: @AlexTbk: how did you solve the problem? I am in similar situation. Please reply.

Comment: i dont remember exactly, but I can see that the method signature has changed: public String save(HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redir){} and the user which is being edited is loaded with the submitted id:             user = userService.getById(UUID.fromString(request.getParameter("id")));